# How to add a drop cap in a .docx file using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, formatting, python-docx, drop-cap

I am trying to add a drop cap to some paragraphs of a Word (`.docx`) document using `python`.
I know this is possible with [Aspose](https://reference.aspose.com/words/python-net/aspose.words/dropcapposition/) but I do want to use free/open source software.
I can easily modify the text of a paragraph to add a new paragraph before that contains only the first letter in capital and with a bigger font size using `python-docx`. But this results in 2 paragraphs and not in a drop cap.